# Creating subtabs in netsuite only for given transaction types

Tags: netsuite

I have a tab that i would like to show ONLY on purchase orders and not other transaction types.  That tab essentially has an associated custom record's fields on it.

First I made a custom TRANSACTION subtab called "PO Acknowledgement Tab".

Next I have a custom record that I would like to be related to purchase orders only.   I made a custom record (call it PO Acknoledgement) that has a number of fields (one of which is a field that is a 'parent transaction' ("record is parent" setting on the field is checked) field that points to the transaction. and of this parent field on the bottom is select that new tab I created.  The rest of the fields have no tab set.

This shows just as I would like but the issue is I see it on ANY transaction since the "parent" record field is a Transaction and I cant figure how to filter to only show this tab on PO screens.  How would this need to be done to accomplish that?

### First is a screen shot of the field inside the custom PO Ack record

[image: screen shot showing the custom field that is part of PO Acknowledgement]

---

### And below is the full PO Acknowledgment Record

[image]

Comment: I guess what I am saying is this is a parent child relationship but its really only relevant as a parent PO transaction and child relationship so perhaps there is some way to define that as such

Comment: In your custom field, in the `Sourcing & Filtering`, can you add a filter `Filter Using = Type` with `Compare Type = equal` to `Value Is = Purchase Order` and see if that restrict it to only the PO form?

Comment: Can you modify the entry forms for other transactions to remove that tab?

Comment: I realize that can be done but here is the issue I have.. this tab and record is in a bundle that others may be getting and I was hoping that there was an approach that would not put the burden on them to change their existing std. or custom forms so I was not sure that was an option?

Comment: Relating to the first comment about sourcing - this is not a custom field it is a custom record that may have fields on it.   I am not sure that was clear or not.

Comment: WS - I think that seemed to work.   I misunderstood what you were describing.

Answer (score 0):

WS Was correct it seems. "In your custom field, in the Sourcing & Filtering, can you add a filter Filter Using = Type with Compare Type = equal to Value Is = Purchase Order and see if that restrict it to only the PO form? –
W.S"